# Partial View within Partial View in MVC: Good or bad practice?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, model-view-controller, partial-views

What are the implications of having a partial view within another partial view? Is it good or bad practice, what problems can occur, does it require any workarounds etc?

Comment: If its for editing, you will possibly have problems unless you passing the `HtmlFieldPrefix` to the partial

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The only problem I see is that when logic is complicated, you'll need multiple viewmodels to be passed to your main view. And you have to handle it somehow. When it comes to testing application, it may require additional efforts.

You can store these viewmodels in ViewBag, but it seems a code smell. If you don't have much logic in these views, or if they use the same viewmodel, it's absolutely fine.

If you have very complicated logic in your views, try thinking about something like Angular, ReactJS. You'll have multiple views on the client side and will be able to test your app.